# Arduino MySQL connector - SELECT statement returns NULL

Tags: c++, mysql, arduino

I am trying to get DB data using SELECT. But Unfortunately, I always get NULL even though I have data in the database. The following is my code ( i didn't include the server details and include statements). If I put all the codes inside the void loop, instead of a function like void check_parameter(), everything works !. But why it isn't working when it is inside a function?

```
int device_id = 1;
String Parameter[3] = {"one", "two", "three"};   // aim is to update these values with db data

EthernetClient client;
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);

const char QUERY_PARA[] = "SELECT ref_time, val_first, val_second  FROM test_db.test_table WHERE Id=  %lu;";
char query[128];

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while (!Serial);
    Ethernet.begin(mac_addr);   
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("inside the loop....");
    delay(10000);
    check_parameter();
}


void check_parameter()
{
  if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password))
    {
        Serial.println("calling the check_para....");
        delay(5000);
       
        MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
        sprintf(query, QUERY_PARA, device_id);

        cur_mem->execute(query);
        column_names *cols = cur_mem->get_columns();

        Serial.println();
        row_values *row = NULL;

        do
        {
            row = cur_mem->get_next_row();
            if (row != NULL)
            {
              // here is the problem. the row is always NULL! I dunno why ??
                Parameter[0] = String(row->values[0]);
                Parameter[1] = String(row->values[1]);
                Parameter[2] = String(row->values[2]);
               
                cur_mem->free_row_buffer();
            }
        } while (row != NULL);
        cur_mem->free_columns_buffer();
        delete cur_mem;
       
        Serial.println("printing parameters");
        Serial.println(Parameter[0]);
        Serial.println(Parameter[1]);
        Serial.println(Parameter[2]);

        conn.close();
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Connection failed.");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you check your MySQL server logs to see that the query you're executing is what you expect to be executing? For that matter you could send it to the serial monitor.